# Can't figure out this error with Cucumber "Can't find mapping from"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber

I am trying to get used to BDD with Cucumber and I wrote a few features already but this one in particular I am confused about, here is the error:

```
Scenario:                                                               # features/viewing_posts.feature:6
Given there is a post with the title "Just another day at the beach"  # features/step_definitions/post_steps.rb:1
And I am on the homepage                                              # features/step_definitions/web_steps.rb:44
When I follow "Just another day at the beach"                         # features/step_definitions/web_steps.rb:56
Then I should be on the post page for "Just another day at the beach" # features/step_definitions/web_steps.rb:230
  Can't find mapping from "the post page for "Just another day at the beach"" to a path.
  Now, go and add a mapping in /Users/jeff/rails_projects/jeffc/features/support/paths.rb (RuntimeError)
  ./features/support/paths.rb:29:in `rescue in path_to'
  ./features/support/paths.rb:23:in `path_to'
  ./features/step_definitions/web_steps.rb:233:in `/^(?:|I )should be on (.+)$/'
  features/viewing_posts.feature:10:in `Then I should be on the post page for "Just another day at the beach"'

Failing Scenarios:
cucumber features/viewing_posts.feature:6 # Scenario:
```

I checked my web_steps.rb in that error and I have the step that should match.

```
Then /^(?:|I )should be on (.+)$/ do |page_name|
  current_path = URI.parse(current_url).path
  if current_path.respond_to? :should
    current_path.should == path_to(page_name)
  else
    assert_equal path_to(page_name), current_path
  end
end
```

It's passing up until the "Then I should be on the post page..."

Can anyone suggest what's going on with this?

Thanks

J

Comment: what should I have to do in path.rb?

Comment: @Aravin nothing, should be able to just leave it as is. Are you having issues?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's expecting to find a path mapping in `paths.rb`

```
Now, go and add a mapping in /Users/jeff/rails_projects/jeffc/features/support/paths.rb (RuntimeError)
```

You might need to move it. Do your other tests have this same issue by chance, or do they work with what you've already got?

Comment: OMG, im sorry for the noise, thanks normalocity. That was exactly it.

Comment: No worries. Cucumber tries to tell you everything you need to do, but when I was new to it I didn't see half the crap it was trying to tell me either.